# In Bash, how do you compare two files (not case sensitive)

Tags: bash, comparison, glob

I figured out how to compare two files and use the status code of that to see if the files are the same or not. The problem is, it only works if the comparison is case sensitive. I used the status code of the cmp command.

I suspect I am to use globbing (i.e. "*[Aa][Bb][Cc][and so on...]*"). But I don't know how to implement this into the cmp command.

Comment: Have you tried `man diff`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is utility for comparing 2 files in shell.

```
 diff -i file1 file2
```

Comment: This is perfect—I don't know why I overlooked diff. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: `diff` is very inefficient compared to `cmp`, as it goes to the trouble of calculating a delta (an algorithm which has worst-case performance on the order of n^3, if memory serves).

Answer (score 3):

Much faster than `diff` is to use `cmp`, after normalizing for case:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ^-- must not be /bin/sh, as process substitution is a bash/ksh/zsh feature

if cmp -s <(tr [a-z] [A-Z] <file1) <(tr [a-z] [A-Z] <file2); then
  echo "files are the same"
else
  echo "files differ"
fi
```

`cmp -s` is particularly fast, as it can exit as soon as it finds the first difference.

This is also much more memory-efficient -- it streams content through the `tr` operation (storing no more than one buffer's worth of each file at any given time), into `cmp` (which, likewise, needs to only store enough to immediately buffer and compare). Compare to a `diff`-type algorithm, which needs to be able to seek around in files to find similar parts, and which thus has IO or memory requirements well beyond the `O(1)` usage of `cmp`.